# Can't Bind Property in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, data-binding, angular2-services, property-binding

Why is there a problem in binding a property on the same component? I already added Input() but still doesn't work. Do i need to put Input() even though it is on the same component when binding?

```
//output.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-output',
  templateUrl: './output.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./output.component.css']
})
export class OutputComponent implements OnInit {
data: {name: string};
datas = [];

constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

ngOnInit(){
   this.datas = this.dataService.datas;
}
}



//output.component.html
<p *ngFor="let data of datas"></p>
<p>{{data.name}}</p>


//data.service.ts
export class DataService {
  datas= [];

  addData(name: string){
     return this.datas.push({name: name});
  } 
}
```

Comment: You dont need to get the data again from the service if you already have the data using input,

Comment: @Sajeetharan. I removed the Input() but still not binding

Comment: post your service code

Comment: @Sajeetharan. Pls check

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with `[data]="data`? What do you expect to see happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For same component `@input API` is not required. It is used when you want to pass the data from Parentcomponent to a child component.

```
//output.component.html
<p *ngFor="let data of dataService.datas" >  // removed [data]="data" and added dataService.datas
   <p>{{data?.name}}</p>
</p>                                         //changed the position of </p>


export class OutputComponent implements OnInit {
   constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}
}
```

---

```
export class DataService {
   datas= [];

   addData(name: string){
      return this.datas.push({name: name});   //return keyword was missing
   } 
}
```

Just for your reference

**DEMO: https://plnkr.co/edit/XlJM2LHFwlAYpQe2ancM?p=preview**

Comment: Yes. Posted  it when you were making your answer!

Comment: try this `{{data?.name}}` and let me know.

Comment: @micronyks. No error but it doesn't output anything in the browser

Comment: Yeah. you need to add data. so click on add button or try to add data and see.

Comment: @micronyks. I did and put console.log on the output.component.ts in "this.datas" and it has data in it

Comment: I updated my answer. Please get rid of ngOninit block. It is no longer required. change your html and service as shown in my answer.

Comment: @micronyks. Unexpected closing tag "p". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag. For more info see https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tags ("
<p *ngFor="let data of dataService.datas" > 
   <p>{{data?.name}}</p>
[ERROR ->]</p>

Comment: try to use `div`inside `p` instead of `p` tag